# Web API introduction for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, api

I've never accessed a web API, and I'm looking for a thorough introduction.  Specifically, I want to access Google APIs from a Mac OS X application.  I can successfully find similar code, copy and paste, but I really want to understand how this all works, and can not find any beginner text of the subject.

Comment: Please flesh out which examples you've looked at; maybe someone can then explain one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's introduction to using `NSURLConnection` is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE), and there's some Apple sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleURLConnections_txt.html). Google also has a [gdata-objectivec-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) client library, which I've never used, but sounds like a drop-in solution to accessing Google's data services. The Google project page has links to overview slides, an introduction and example applications.